# Going back to previous location in TexShop

Tags: texshop

TexShop has two useful little triangles in its pdf preview toolbar which allow me to go back to the previous location in the pdf file.

Does the TexShop text editor have a similar feature?  Sometimes I move in the tex file to make a quick edit and it would be great if I could go back quickly to my previous location. Alternatively, can I save my current location and then come back to it with a some special key strike? I looked through the menu and googled that, but didn't find anything. (There is a roundabout way, by syncing pdf preview, and then using it to go back, but it is not very convenient.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While TeXShop itself doesn't have this feature the Apple Text Framework used by TeXShop has many commands that aren't bound to keys. Quite a few are related to similar commands from emacs. One pair in particular may be of use here. The `point` is the location of the cursor and a `mark` is an invisible saved location in a file. The two commands first create a `mark` at the location of the `point` (e.g., the place you want to return to) and, after moving the point somewhere else, a command to swap the `point` and the `mark` which will bring you back to that point. To see how to enable these commands, and more, download `KeyBindings.zip` from [my download site](https://herbs.github.io) which contains information about binding those keystrokes as well as a sample file that binds those commands and instructions of where to put it.

NOTE: those binding will work for all apps that use the Apple Text Framework, e.g., Mail.

Comment: This is awesome! Many thanks.